# Does Undefined Behavior depend on the compiler in c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, undefined-behavior

Does Undefined Behavior depend on the compiler in c++ ?

Every compiler have its own behavior for every problem !

Comment: It can depend on the compiler, or the architecture, or the environment.

Comment: how to say it ? Yes ? Undefined is undefined. Playing Mahler's 6th symphony while dereferencing a null pointer is permitted by the standard. Voting to close as non constructive. Explaining undefined behavior is worth something only in a few very specific cases.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined really does mean undefined. That is, anything can happen.

Can it depend on the compiler? Yes.

Can all compilers do the same thing? Yes.

Can it do one thing today and one thing tomorrow? Yes.

Can it make the program crash? Yes.

Can it do what I think it should do and seem to work fine? Yes.

Anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Undefined Behavior,
**C++ Standard section 1.3.24 states:**

> Permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

So, Yes a compiler is free to show any behavior they want when Undefined Behavior occurs.

Answer (score 1):

What constitutes undefined behavior is specified in the C++ standard.

What code a compiler generates when it runs into code that exhibits undefined behavior can be, by definition, anything. This is to give compiler writers leeway for optimizations.

Note that undefined behavior means your program can do ANYTHING. It does not guarantee it will crash, or throw an exception, or write to a certain area of memory. For all you know, it can delete your entire filesystem and then take out the trash - and that would be okay by the C++ standard.

Stay away from undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure it's to do with leeway for optimizations.

Comment: Perhaps optimizations was not the right word. It's usually used in cases where defining a standard behavior would make something hard or inefficient to support on all architectures. So, to make it easier on the developers, they just allow them to do whatever is easiest/most efficient for the given architecture. A lot of times this is to do nothing and leave the program in a possibly inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Undefined Behavior depend on the compiler in c++ ?

**Yes**.
It can be argued like this:

> Well defined behavior is standard compliant and is supported by all
>   the compilers equally well.

Thus,

> Undefined behavior is not standard compliant and the compilers are
>   free to do whatever they want!